# mismatch between legend/figure in plot

Tags: r, plot, colors, levels

first of all, apologies, I know that this question has been asked before but none of the solutions i found seems to be working for me... R will stubbornly refuse to plot the right colors in my legend

I have the following data

```
V11.y PC1 PC2 V6.y V7.y V8.y V9.y V10.y
1 Abditibacterium -7.528935e+14 -3.092266e+14 Bacteria Abditibacteriota Abditibacteria Abditibacteriales Abitibacteriaceae
2 Abidjanvirus -7.557715e+14 -3.109203e+13 Viruses unclassified unclassified Caudovirales Siphoviridae
3 Abiotrophia -7.491173e+14 -3.047456e+14 Bacteria Firmicutes Bacilli Lactobacillales Aerococcaceae
4 Abrus -7.557715e+14 -3.109203e+14 Eukaryota Streptophyta Magnoliopsida Fabales Fabaceae
5 Abscondita -7.537974e+14 -3.098546e+14 Eukaryota Arthropoda Insecta Coleoptera Lampyridae
6 Absicoccus -5.600170e+13 -1.933629e+14 Bacteria Firmicutes Erysipelotrichia Erysipelotrichales Erysipelotrichaceae
7 Absidia -7.555506e+14 -3.105756e+14 Eukaryota Mucoromycota Mucoromycetes Mucorales Cunninghamellaceae
8 Absiella -2.072363e+14 7.305995e+14 Bacteria Firmicutes Erysipelotrichia Erysipelotrichales Erysipelotrichaceae
9 Abyssibacter -7.543130e+14 -3.103792e+14 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria Salinisphaerales Salinisphaeraceae
10 Abyssicoccus -7.511899e+14 -3.069448e+14 Bacteria Firmicutes Bacilli Bacillales Staphylococcaceae
11 Abyssisolibacter -7.067138e+14 -2.700463e+14 Bacteria Firmicutes Clostridia Clostridiales Clostridiaceae
12 Acadevirus -7.557715e+14 -3.109203e+13 Viruses Uroviricota Caudoviricetes Caudovirales Autographiviridae
13 Acanthamoeba -7.534538e+14 -3.101502e+14 Eukaryota Discosea unclassified Longamoebia Acanthamoebidae
14 Acanthaster -7.557668e+13 -3.109202e+14 Eukaryota Echinodermata Asteroidea Valvatida Acanthasteridae
```

this is just the first 14 out of 4600 rows

I am trying to plot the V11.y using the PC1 and PC2 coordinates and by coloring them either with the V6.y or with the V7.y or even with the V8.y.

This is what I have been trying:

```
plot(sitesplus$PC1, sitesplus$PC2, type="n")

sitesplus$V6.y=as.factor(sitesplus$V6.y)
text(sitesplus$PC1, sitesplus$PC2, labels = sitesplus$V11.y, col=c(sitesplus$V6.y))

legend("topleft",
   legend=sort(unique(sitesplus$V6.y)), 
   col=c(sitesplus$V6.y),
   pch=19,
   text.font=c(1),
   cex=1,
   bty="n")
```

I can see that the "Bacteria" is black, the "Viruses" green and the "Eukaryota" red. But the legend claims sth entirely different!

I also tried:

```
legend("topleft",
   legend=levels(sitesplus$V6.y), 
   col=c(sitesplus$V6.y),
   pch=19,
   text.font=c(1),
   cex=1,
   bty="n")
```

even though in the above case I know that the "levels" changes the order but I cannot figure out a simple solution to make this work!!!

Btw I cannot specify the 4 colors because this is just an example and at some point I will have hundred different levels that i m gonna want to plot so specifying the colors in advance will not work for me.

any help will be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `text`, `PC1`, `PC2`, and `V6.y` (your arg for `col=`) are all the same length. In your call to `legend`, you are still including the same-length `V6.y` for `col` even though it really needs length 3 (in this case), one (unique) color for each of the `levels` in the variable.

It shows what it did because the text of the legend only includes 3 objects, so it is grabbing the first three integers from the `factor`. In this sample data, it's `c("Bacteria","Viruses","Bacteria")`, or `c(1,3,1)` (black green black).

Try this,

```r
plot(sitesplus$PC1, sitesplus$PC2, type="n")
text(sitesplus$PC1, sitesplus$PC2, labels = sitesplus$V11.y, col=c(sitesplus$V6.y))
legend("topleft",
   legend=levels(sitesplus$V6.y), 
   col=seq_along(levels(sitesplus$V6.y)),
   pch=19,
   text.font=c(1),
   cex=1,
   bty="n")
```

[image: plot with corrected legend colors]

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, both for the explanation and the fix, didnt know about the "seq_along"!